# MySql and Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, mysql, frameworks, entity

I have a problem with MySql and Entity Framework Code First.

My Connection String at the web.config.xml

```
<add name="EntityContext" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1; port=8080 Database=simple_crud; Uid=root; Pwd=;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

My Context:

```
public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
}
```

My Class:

```
[Table("pessoa")]
public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
public EntityContext db = new EntityContext();

public ActionResult Index()
{
     List<Pessoa> pessoas = db.Pessoas.ToList(); // here is the error
     return View(pessoas);
}
```

So, when I press F5 I got this: "Input string was not in a correct format".

What I'm miss?

**UPDATE**

Stack Trace:

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   +9591147    System.Number.ParseUInt32(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +119
>   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
>   +46    System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +9509065
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.ChangeType(Object
>   value, Type t) +240
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.SetValue(String
>   keyword, Object value) +399
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String
>   keyword, Object value) +54
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value) +127
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value) +289
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String
>   name) +409
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +49
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()
>   +10    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +265    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +17
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +62
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
>   +40    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +58    SimpleMysqlCrud.Controllers.PessoaController.Index() in
>   f:\users\pablo.rocha.fti\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\SimpleMysqlCrud\SimpleMysqlCrud\Controllers\PessoaController.cs:16
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12()
>   +55    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +343
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +97    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   *) +12    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62    System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +50
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +7 
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
>   +22    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8970141    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Comment: Which line is the exception on?

Comment: You forgot to add semicolon after **port=8080** no?

Comment: @AndreyVoloshin, give me a example please.

Comment: @DStanley, the exception is here: db.Pessoas.ToList()

Comment: Please post the stack trace as well.

Comment: <add name="EntityContext" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1; **port=8080;** Database=simple_crud; Uid=root; Pwd=;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />

Comment: @AndreyVoloshin, I did:

`<add name="EntityContext" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1; port=8080; Database=simple_crud; Uid=root; Pwd=;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />`

and i got this:

**Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.**

Comment: Are you sure that your database port not 3306? (MySql standart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gathering all comments into answer.

Add semicolon after port=3306; and check your mysql listening port (maybe 3306, mysql default?). Resulting connection string:

```
<add name="EntityContext" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1; port=3306; Database=simple_crud; Uid=root; Pwd=;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Comment: Port is Default. It is not necessary to put

Answer (score 0):

MySql Default Port is 3306; So no  Need to mention this here,

Eg:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdb;UID=test;PASSWORD=test123;" />
```