# Swapping to MySQL from SQL Server 2008 with ASP.NET MVC, LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am considering migrating from SQL Server 2008 to MySQL to save on licencing costs.

I was wanting to know if this would work and what sort of problems it might cause.

As I used EF Code first for the database, my databse is automatically generated based on my class structure. Would this, the entity framework and LINQ still work with a MySQL database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework is pretty old but has some relevant info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes EF and LINQ works with MySQL as well, please take a look at these posts.
[Entity Framework 5.0 code-first with MySQL Connector 6.6.5.0 on .Net 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410817/entity-framework-5-0-code-first-with-mysql-connector-6-6-5-0-on-net-4-5)

and
[MySql and Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361314/mysql-and-entity-framework-code-first)